# What is the route for a specific node?

Tags: routes, 9

I want to override the `user.login` route that points to the default login page.

I.e. I want that a user who presses the default "Log in" link for the site to be directed to a *node* that provides some help (where the user can click on a link and arrive at the standard log-in form).

Say that the path I want to redirect to is `/node/42`. How can I find out what route to return for a specific node?

I believe that the right place to do this in Drupal 9 is to override the `getRouteName()` function the in the `LoginLogoutMenuLink` class.  So I'm trying to create something like this.

```
public function getRouteName() {
  if ($this->currentUser->isAuthenticated()) {
    return 'user.logout';
  }
  else {
    return '- What to put here? - ';
  }
}
```

I've searched a lot, and some people say that the route for nodes are `entity.node.canonical`. But that does not solve it for me. I think that the route for a *specific* node also need to have the `nid` in there somewhere.

Comment: See the answer from @sonfd and override `getRouteParameters()` to return the parameter array with the node id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless something is overriding the routing, the route for all nodes is `entity.node.canonical`.

The route needs a route_parameter, `node`, to pass the nid.

For example, you could create a link to a node's page with [Link::createFromRoute()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Link.php/function/Link%3A%3AcreateFromRoute/9.2.x) like:

```
$my_link = Link::createFromRoute('My link text', 'entity.node.canonical', [
  'node' => 123,
]);
```

As @4k4 pointed out, you'll need to create the LoginLogoutMenuLink class's `getRouteName()` and `getRouteParameters()` methods.

```
public function getRouteName() {
  if ($this->currentUser->isAuthenticated()) {
    return 'user.logout';
  }
  else {
    return 'entity.node.canonical';
  }
}

public function getRouteParameters() {
  // Not sure if this is the best conditional to use here.
  if ($this->getRouteName() == 'entity.node.canonical') {
    return [
      'node' => 123,
    ];
  }

  return parent::getRouteParameters();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just had to amend it slightly to make it work. See updated questing for working version.